# I want to design hurdles like used in jetpack joyride

Tags: java, android, libgdx, game-engine

How can I design hurdle pattern as going easy to tough like magical ride(facebook), jetpack joy ride etc.
I am able to design separately but i want more optimize way to do this.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
 { 
  System.out.println(j);
 }
}
```

this will give me triangle shape but I want more complex design so is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Well a better approch is to make a 2d array

```
            int[][] coinMatrix1 =
    {
                { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
                { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    };
        generateCoinMatrix(coinMatrix1);


public void generateCoinMatrix(int[][] coinMatrix2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            if (coinMatrix2[i][j] == 1)
            {
                coin = dummyCoinsCollection.get(countCoinFromDummy);
                coin.coinEffectShow = false; // by me
                coin.position.x = coinSetPos.x + j * (coinSizeX);
                coin.position.y = coinSetPos.y + (5 - i) * (coinSizeX);
                coin.setBounds(coin.position.x, coin.position.y);
                coinMatrix[i][j] = coin;
                countCoinFromDummy++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This way u can make any pattern you want.